# Combinatorics based binary sequence

Tags: combinatorics, binary

We all know the standard base-$2$ representation of integers and many of you will know of Gray codes. Does anybody know of a name (or something I can use to find a good reference) for a method of sequencing a binary representation so that numbers higher in the sequence have more bits set? For example,

$$000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, 111.$$

We set $i$ bits until all $n \choose i$ combinations are used, then increment $i$. Does this sequence have a name?

Answer (score 2):

This would be ordering binary words by bit count (sideways sum, Hamming weight) and lexicographically within one class. Don't know of any more standard name for this ordering.

There is actually a fairly fast algorithm to find the lexicographically next word with the same bit count if it exists. It is a nice exercice to describe it.